# How to wait X seconds a click after one was recently made? - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delay the trigger of a click after one was recently triggered. Why? Because in my website I can simply click multiple times the "dropdown icon" and it will toggle the slide those multiple times and dont want to... I mean, I want to wait till the dropdown menu was slided and then it can trigger another click in the "dropdown icon"

My website url is: www.ayfshowroom.byethost5.com

I'm new using jquery, this is my code:

```
    function desplegarMenu () { //DESPLIEGA MENU EN RESPONSIVE
    $('#dropdown').click(function() {
        $('.container-menu ul').slideToggle(500);
        $('#dropdown i').toggleClass("fa fa-bars").toggleClass("fa fa-times");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    desplegarMenu();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want people to essentially be able to 'cancel' their action and toggle the menu back immediately? It's nice to be able to have that responsive feeling as a user and to not have to wait for an animation to complete.

Comment: Its a nice question but I dont think it looks nice when people make those multiple clicks in the item and the dropdown menu becomes crazy hahaha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch for when the animation finishes, and only react to the click event when it is finished.

```
// create a new variable to record whether the animation is in progress
var dropdownAnimating = false;

function desplegarMenu () { //DESPLIEGA MENU EN RESPONSIVE
    $('#dropdown').click(function() {
        // if the animation is in progress, don't do anything
        if (dropdownAnimating) return;

        // set the flag that the drop down is animating
        dropdownAnimating = true;

        // use the complete function to reset the flag when the animation is complete
        $('.container-menu ul').slideToggle(500, function() { dropdownAnimating = false; });

        $('#dropdown i').toggleClass("fa fa-bars").toggleClass("fa fa-times");
    });
}
```

In this way, if the user clicks whilst the animation is in progress, nothing will happen.

Comment: This is nice, but you don't need to use an options object for `slideToggle` if you don't want. You can simply use `.slideToggle(500, function() { dropdownAnimating = false; });`

Comment: Im just an idiot, its just a great idea to use a flag hahaha. Just tested and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the toogler button when animating...

```
$('#dropdown').click(function() {
    var self = this;
    $(self).prop("disabled",true); //disabling the button, to prevent another click
    $('.container-menu ul').slideToggle(500, function() {
        $(self).prop("disabled",false); //enabling the button after animation
    });
    $('#dropdown i').toggleClass("fa fa-bars").toggleClass("fa fa-times");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't wait for the animation to end, it will disable and then enable in the button pretty much immediately.

Comment: You are right :) I made a change to my post, It may work that way